# Free hosting of Spring war file

Tags: java, spring, hosting, war, free

I'm new into web hosting and wanted to **host** a **.war file**, that uses Spring technology, **for free**. It is just a small application and I don't want to pay any money for the hosting. Has anyone an idea?

By the way, I'm not really into networking, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try heroku, you can find details here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

Comment: Thanks, is it free permanently?

Comment: There are free and paid plans, for free plans you can check their limitations here:
https://www.heroku.com/free